# Get the main page where i publish post

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m from `page.php`  I go to the `single.php` category page for example `site.com/view-page-where-show-post/post-in-single/` and there is the navigation “next post and previous post” and I need to make a cross to exit page.php where I switched to single.php. I tried to use this `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`, but when I move to the next category, it returns the link of the last step to me, and I need to have `site.com/view-page-where-show-post/` I don’t know how to leave one hole on all single.php.

I tried to use this
`<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_field( 'close_page_return_from_referenzen' ), 'option' )  ?>">back </a>` but it return me `site.com/view-page-where-show-post/post-in-single/%post-in-single%` but i want `site.com/view-page-where-show-post/`

please help me

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by _“and I need to make a cross to exit page.php where I switched to single.php”_ to begin with here.

Comment: I am on `site.com/view-page-where-show-post/post-in-single/` and I need to make the back button and return to `site.com/view-page-where-show-post/`

Comment: Have you use any child parent concept ?

Comment: no, I just have page.php, there I have the output of posts. I click on post and go to it. At the bottom I have switches between posts, but I still need to make a button that will throw me back to page.php

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. 
I had an error in displaying a custom field

```
<div class="exit-link"><a href="<?php echo get_field( 'close_page_return_from_referenzen', 'option')   ?>">back <span class="icon-close-1"><span> </span></span></a></div>
```